# Centering CARTO map in iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, cartodb

I want to embed a CARTO map in an iframe, but centering it to a specific location and zoom. I would also want to dinamically change center and zoom with javascript.

I've been reading CARTO documentation and could not find it out, and I've found this answer https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/136211/iframe-map-adjusts-to-cartodb-zoom-centering but it's not working in my case. I noticed address in my map is not using /viz/ (but /builder/) neither /embed_map (but /embed), I'm wondering if it's due to the update CARTO did a few time ago, or because it's free plan.

https://obsa-andorra.carto.com/builder/a01df589-663b-41a4-a7a2-f3bb9d2cf871

Answer (score 0):

The answer of the GIS SE you have commented is not going to work with your embed map. As mentioned [in CARTO website](https://carto.com/learn/guides/intro/migrating-from-carto-editor-to-carto-builder#temporary-limitations), CARTO.js v3.15 is not compatible with BUILDER `vizjson`s. But if you want to build a custom map application, you can still use `createLayer` ([here](http://bl.ocks.org/oriolbx/f9a75b1dc017e7a8af2a) you have a working example) method and add javascript interactions.

Comment: If I understand correctly, a new map is generated with Leaflet instead of embedding the already done Carto map. That's not exactly what I was trying to achieve, I will keep it in mind though. Thanks.